# Group data by a tolerance

Tags: python

I have an ordered list

> L = [301.148986835,
> 301.148986835,
> 301.148986835,
> 301.161562835,
> 301.161562835,
> 301.16156333500004,
> 301.167179835,
> 301.167179835,
> 301.167179835,
> 301.167179835,
> 301.167179835,
> 301.179755835,
> 301.179755835,
> 301.179755835,
> 301.646611835,
> 301.659187335,
> 301.659187335,
> 301.659187335,
> 301.659187335,
> 302.138619335,
> 302.142316335,
> 302.151194835,
> 302.1568118349999,
> 302.15681183500004,
> 302.15681183500004,
> 302.15681183500004,
> 302.156812335,
> 302.156812335,
> 302.156812335,
> 302.169387835,
> 302.169387835,
> 302.169387835,
> 302.169387835,
> 302.169387835,
> 302.169388335,
> 302.636243335,
> 302.636243835,
> 302.648819835,
> 302.648819835,
> 303.137565335,
> 303.140827335,
> 303.140827335,
> 303.146443835,
> 303.146443835,
> 303.146444335,
> 303.159019835,
> 303.159019835,
> 303.15901983500004,
> 303.159020335,
> 303.159020335,
> 303.15902033500004,
> 303.63283533500004,
> 303.638451335,
> 304.130459335,
> 304.130459335,
> 304.14370483499994,
> 304.14370483499994,
> 304.14370483499994,
> 304.148651835,
> 304.148652335,
> 304.148652335]

I want to group it with a margin of +-0.5

The expected output

> ```
>  R = [[301.148986835,
>   301.148986835,
>   301.148986835,
>   301.161562835,
>   301.161562835,
>   301.16156333500004,
>   301.167179835,
>   301.167179835,
>   301.167179835,
>   301.167179835,
>   301.167179835,
>   301.179755835,
>   301.179755835,
>   301.179755835,
>   301.646611835,
>   301.659187335,
>   301.659187335,
>   301.659187335,
>   301.659187335,
>   302.138619335],[302.142316335,
>   302.151194835,
>   302.1568118349999,
>   302.15681183500004,
>   302.15681183500004,
>   302.15681183500004,
>   302.156812335,
>   302.156812335,
>   302.156812335,
>   302.169387835,
>   302.169387835,
>   302.169387835,
>   302.169387835,
>   302.169387835,
>   302.169388335,
>   302.636243335,
>   302.636243835,
>   302.648819835,
>   302.648819835,
>   303.137565335,
>   303.140827335,
>   303.140827335,
>   303.146443835,
>   303.146443835,
>   303.146444335,
>   303.159019835,
>   303.159019835,
>   303.15901983500004,
>   303.159020335,
>   303.159020335,
>   303.15902033500004],
> [303.63283533500004,
>   303.638451335,
>   304.130459335,
>   304.130459335,
>   304.14370483499994,
>   304.14370483499994,
>   304.14370483499994],[304.148651835,
>   304.148652335,
>   304.148652335]
> ```

When I use this code (my question is not duplicate

```
def grouper(iterable):
    prev = None
    group = []
    for item in iterable:
        if prev is None or item - prev <= 1:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
        prev = item
    if group:
        yield group
```

I get the same list as an output

calculate within a tolerance

Comment: You update `prev` in every iteration. You want to update it only when you start a new group

Comment: Note that your expected output doesn't make sense with a tolerance of 1, your second group should start at `302.151194835`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update `prev` in every iteration. Because of this, every element of your list is within 1 of `prev`. You want to update it only when you start a new group.

Better yet, get rid of `prev` altogether and always compare against the first element of the group.

I'd also suggest including a `tol` argument so that the function is more flexible:

```
def grouper(iterable, tol=0.5):
    tol = abs(tol*2) # Since we're counting from the start of the group, multiply tol by 2
    group = []
    for item in iterable:
        if not group or item - group[0] <= tol:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [item]
    if group:
        yield group
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##rZNBbsIwEEX3OYWXRWqR7RmP7arcgBsgFlQYGgmSKE0XnD6NSWInQCpoO7v38@ePx3KKU/WRZ1DXS7ZgK@BiLtBYQwbUM7sDSSiSPyIAKN4U9poW2g4sf0BttVJ3IiGREBGVFUbDL1DOBRgSNiJKEBRRCWHRRCTj56JtaizFa3lQkzBKn0ayYLT5NzQhmYAkwgUGM6Exwt5GaK5PK1IQELmRehoJQ/JtxGhWlg8HTWC4zlaTfBRwCwcdBP59X2oGlejasFmQo7KTiKA5dg8CH9UMqf4RdyjhCtdJsnU7ti/zr8KVT2nlys37wc1eE9bUWfZ/@/qMu7xkjePI0oz1ztboK92xLK@6nt750vKKr9nbgonoDvHzTVG4bOtHH2fhszt8urH5lLrDtm25DvFn9AHtOdNuoRgwbE78Gnu/Q7/1slu3KNOsetrP6vob)